# TikZ: how to draw a horizontal line up to a given abscissa, without knowing its starting point?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the picture below, I want to **draw the horizontal line up to the abscissa `x=3`**.
How can I easily do that, without explicitly defining the point where the line breaks (i.e. the "`--++(45:.5)`" point)?

[image]

Here are possible solutions I know, but they are not satisfactory (since too complicated):

- I could define an intersection using the `intersections` library and the vertical line `(3,-10) -- (3,10)`, but it seems an overkill, and messes up the bounding box (I could add a `\clip`... but it would make the code even bulkier);
- I could draw the line `\draw  (45:.75) ++ (45:.5) -| ++(2,0);`, and define a new coordinate at the angle using `[pos=.5]`. But again, it seems to be to much work for that.

---

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
        \draw [<-] (45:.75) -- ++ (45:.5) -- ++(2,0);

        %== below are just 'decoration' to make the picture more obvious ==%
        \draw [help lines] (-1.5,-1.5) grid (3.5,1.5);
        \path [font=\tiny, text=blue] (45:.75) node [left]{\verb|\path (45:.75)|}
            -- ++ (45:.5) node [above] {\verb|-- ++ (45:.5)|}
            -- ++(2,0) node [above] {\verb|-- ++(2,0);|};
        \foreach \x in {-1, ..., 3}{
            \node [below] at (\x,0) {\x};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but then you have to change the decoration `++(2,0)` because there is more then 2cm to reach there is that correct?

Comment: Yes! of course, the `-- ++(2,0)` is what have to be changed.

Comment: Then `\draw [<-] (45:.75) -- ++ (45:.5) coordinate (a) -- (a-| {(3,0)});` would do it

Comment: @percusse yes it does: this is the writing I was looking for! // And what if I want to align the line break (i.e. the start of the horizontal line) with the abscissa `x=1` - without know it should then be a `(1,1)`? [I know it was not in the first question, sorry]

Comment: That's trickier because the path length and the end point is unknown simultaneously. Then you need extras as you mentioned or calculate the hypotenuse with `let`... `in` and so on.

Comment: To align the break point you can use `calc` library with `\draw (O) -- ($(O)!sqrt(2)!45:(O-|A)$)` where `O` is the starting point and the abscissa of `A` is the desired abscissa of the breaking point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to use the `A -| B` operator to compute the position of the point positioned on the abscissa of `B` and on the coordinate of `A`. (Note that you can use `A |- B` for the opposite.)

So you can use either of these solutions:

```
\draw [<-] (45:.75) -- ++ (45:.5) coordinate (a) -- (a-| {(3,0)});
% OR %
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\draw [<-] (45:.75) -- ++ (45:.5) -- ({$(45:.75) + (45:.5)$} -| {(3,0)});
```

The first creates a local coordinate `(a)` on the fly where the arrow breaks. The second re-computes the position of the angle (i.e. coordinate of the starting point + shift to the angle-point).

---

If you plan to do this a lot, you can create a macro to do all the work.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\angled}[3][]% #1=draw options (optional), #2=start, #3=end, use tikz point notation inside braces
{\bgroup% local macros
  \path #2;
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya}%
  \path #3;
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xc}{\xb+.707*(\ya-\yb)}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xd}{\xb+.707*(\yb-\ya)}%
  \ifdim \ya>\yb \relax
    \ifdim \xa<\xb \relax \let\xc=\xd \fi
  \else
    \ifdim \xa>\xb \relax \let\xc=\xd \fi
  \fi
  \draw[#1] #2 -- (\xc,\ya) -- #3;
\egroup}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
        %\draw [<-] (45:.75) -- ++ (45:.5) -- ++(2,0);
        \angled[->]{(2,1)}{(45:.75)}%

        %== below are just 'decoration' to make the picture more obvious ==%
        \draw [help lines] (-1.5,-1.5) grid (3.5,1.5);
        \path [font=\tiny, text=blue] (45:.75) node [left]{\verb|\path (45:.75)|}
            -- ++ (45:.5) node [above] {\verb|-- ++ (45:.5)|}
            -- ++(2,0) node [above] {\verb|-- ++(2,0);|};
        \foreach \x in {-1, ..., 3}{
            \node [below] at (\x,0) {\x};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ebo - You can provide your own answer, and after a couple of days you can even accept it.

Comment: You're right. Actually, I hesitated between adding a new answer or updating yours. Indeed, the solution I chose is the one you gave in comments. Since my edit was mainly based on *your* comment, I though it would be fairer to add details to your answer. But I can understand it might appear a bit weird.